# why load tf.keras.Sequential again and again with joblib cost increasing time

Tags: tensorflow, keras, joblib

It comes to a situation that I need to load the same size model(almost the same scale) one by one, the `joblib.load` kept cost increasing time.
For example, loading the first model token 3 seconds and the second one token 5 seconds. The later one always took more time than the previous one while the latter model is not more complicated. even if I kept loading one same model, again and again, it would cost more and more time as well(time consumption as follows).

```
0 4.4071619510650635 seconds
1 4.408193111419678 seconds
2 5.5284717082977295 seconds
3 7.223154306411743 seconds
4 8.955665111541748 seconds
5 10.984207153320312 seconds
6 12.934542179107666 seconds
7 14.573008298873901 seconds
8 17.183340311050415 seconds
9 19.3760027885437 seconds
```

I don't know why this happened and how can I found a method to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `keras.backend` load all context into a global variable, and keep it running all the way, you can't delete model itself to clean the environment.

Take the following piece of code would release the context, and make the next process much easier.

```
import keras
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

By the way, If you are considering control the session of joblib process, take a look at
`tf.InteractiveSession` or `tf.Session under with`